# Cannot Access FORM POST (403 Forbidden Error)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following piece of code, I am using `Croppie` to upload an image, crop it and save it as base64 data, then on form submission, a php file that takes two parameters runs, saves the image in a specific directory and redirects back to the page. The code was working fine when it was on localhost, but when I hosted it, I get a 403 Forbidden Error when I try accessing the php file. It has nothing to do with permissions and I think it is a security measure. Is there an alternative way to fix this issue, maybe by changing it to an Ajax request, If someone can help me with the code I really appreciate it. Thank you

HTML CODE:

```
               <form type= "text" id="form" method="post"> 
                        <input type="file" id="upload" value="Choose a file">
                        <input type="hidden" id="imagebase64" name="imagebase64">
                        <a href="#" class="upload-result button button-primary full-width">Upload Photo</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="upload-demo" style="float: right ;width:350px"></div>
            </div>




            <script type="text/javascript">
                var USERid2 = null;
                $( document ).ready( function () {
                    var em = '<?php echo $email?>';
                    $.ajax( {
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype: "text",
                        url: "/Proto/PHP/getUserID.php",
                        data: {
                            email: em
                        },
                        success: function ( data ) {
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                            USERid2 = obj;
                            document.getElementById( 'form' ).action = '/Proto/uploadimage.php?USERid=' + USERid2 + '&currURL=' + window.location.href; // this sets form action, which includes the php file and parameters 

                        }
                    } );

                } );



                $( document ).ready( function () {

                    var $uploadCrop;

                    function readFile( input ) {
                        if ( input.files && input.files[ 0 ] ) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function ( e ) {
                                $uploadCrop.croppie( 'bind', {
                                    url: e.target.result
                                } );
                                $( '.upload-demo' ).addClass( 'ready' );
                            }
                            reader.readAsDataURL( input.files[ 0 ] );
                        }
                    }

                    $uploadCrop = $( '#upload-demo' ).croppie( {
                        viewport: {
                            width: 200,
                            height: 200,
                            type: 'circle'
                        },
                        boundary: {
                            width: 300,
                            height: 300
                        }
                    } );

                    $( '#upload' ).on( 'change', function () {
                        readFile( this );
                    } );
                    $( '.upload-result' ).on( 'click', function ( ev ) {
                        $uploadCrop.croppie( 'result', {
                            type: 'canvas',
                            size: 'original'
                        } ).then( function ( resp ) {
                            $( '#imagebase64' ).val( resp );
                            $( '#form' ).submit(); 
                        } );
                    } );

                } );
            </script>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php


$id= $_GET['USERid'];
$url= $_GET['currURL'];
if(isset($_POST['imagebase64'])){
    $data = $_POST['imagebase64'];
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $file = "../../Proto/SiteResources/ProfilePictures/" . $id . '.jpg';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
    header("Location: $url");
}

?>
```

Comment: `'&currURL=' + window.location.href` I think you have to escape this with `encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)` (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: still giving me 403 Forbidden Error....

Comment: 403 Forbidden usually comes from the webserver. Are you sure all the configuration is correct?

Comment: Is there a way to enable accessing POST using URL on the web server? I am using CPANEL